# How to use tubular.js properly, so that the youtube video is in the background of my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using tubular.js and wanted to set up the youtube video as a background.

So far I have the following html code:

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.tubular.1.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var options = {
                    videoId : '9JXVUP1hyxA',
                    start : 10
                };
                $('html').tubular(options);
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but the video is almost on the full screen, but there are still around 5-10 px around - you can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGH35.jpg). How can I prevent that?
And another question, maybe you will guys know - I have the video on repeat and it works, but when it reaches the end - just before starting again there's a blank screen with other video suggestions that is always visible on youtube after the video is played. It's visible for couple milliseconds, but still a little bit weird - do you know how to solve that issue? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, because you code is not full. But I think you need this one:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

And try to read more, about [CSS reset](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=reset%20css)!

About second question, I don't used tubular.js before, but here is nice [example](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/) just try to copy it.